# Create Grid of images with multiple columns and header

Tags: android, gridview, grid, android-gridview, android-tablelayout

I would like to create this layout in my app, dynamically:

The maximum number of levels would be 4, and the squares represent Images (3 only shown below)

[image: Multiple grid views]

I tried using multiple grid views to build this but it didn't work. Each gridview has its own scrolling capabilities and only the first item of each grid was visible.

Could someone recommend an alternative way to building this e.g Tablelayout.

The problem I find with Tablelayout is specifying the number of columns and having to resize the images along the way.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score -1):

If you create an adapter, you could set the number of columns dynamically using a switch statement, depending on the number of images to view : [Grid View Example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

In the XML you can use the following in your GridView widget to adjust the number of columns :

```
android:numColumns="4"
```

Or to do it dynamically you can use  :

```
mAdapter.setNumColumns(numColumns)
```

Comment: i specifically mentioned that I had tried using Gridviews but only one row was visible for each gridview...

Comment: Then you aren't using Grid Views correctly. You specifically stated that you are using multiple Grid Views, this isn't needed. Just use one and adjust the size and columns accordingly.